how do I replace built-in algorithms on my PixHawk/ardupilot with custom reinforcement learning algorithms m?
I’ve been working on a drone project for 2 months now. Originally, it was supposed to take 2 only weeks. Everyday, there’s a new, unexpected problem that ends of being more difficult than it seems.
My newest hurdle is implementing RL functionalities I’ve read about(on arxiv for example) in research papers.
So before I dive deep and get stuck again, I’d like to get an outline of the solution steps.
Question: when implementing reinforcement learning algorithms from a research paper (on a PixHawk/Ardupilot), is it the kalman filters related algorithms I’ll need to replace? Example algorithm could be RL for extremely stable hovering, wall following, precision landing, obstacle avoidance, etc.
Supporting details:
I ask this because I’ve never worked on a project like this before. The exact confusion is that PixHawk/Ardupilot come with built-in KF and EKF algorithms. Hence, if I’m modifying the EKF via RL, how would I override the system’s built-in EKF? I suspect that this is not even possible.
If it is not the Kalman filter that the RL algorithm changes, which algorithm does it change?
All in all, please give me a summary of the solution. This is so that I can narrow down the search space of my research.

paper: GapFlyt: Active Vision Based Minimalist Structure-less Gap Detection For Quadrotor Flight(https://prg.cs.umd.edu/research/gapflyt_files/GapFlyt-RAL2018.pdf)
video demonstration of the paper: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSSqB7ag04w

why are you commenting on your own question? ... if you have anything to add, then edit the question... do not write a comment ... this site is not a forum where you add info down the line
